# How do I search for a command I don't know the complete name of?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, linux-mint, arch-linux

Every time I try to use a program from the terminal, I can't find it because it doesn't match the real name. For example, I type `disks` in terminal, but the real name is `gnome-disks`.

I tried to use:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep disks
```

to find it, but what about programs that do not match at all? What's the easiest way to find all names of installed programs in the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

This will list all man pagenames and short descriptions containing the text "disks". Note that this will ***not*** return anything for scripts or programs that do not have a manpage but every program supplied with the Ubuntu distro should have one...

```
man -k disks
```

OR...

```
apropos disks
```

For example...

```
 root@LX02:~  apropos disks
cryptdisks_start (8) - wrapper around cryptsetup which parses /etc/crypttab.
cryptdisks_stop (8)  - wrapper around cryptsetup which parses /etc/crypttab.
mtools (1)           - utilities to access DOS disks in Unix.
smartctl (8)         - Control and Monitor Utility for SMART Disks
udisks (1)           - udisks command line tool
udisks (7)           - Storage Management
udisks-daemon (8)    - udisks Daemon
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to inspect the "program starter" using the menu editor:

- right-click on the menu button in the taskbar;
- select **`Edit Menu`** - this will open the menu editor.

Now, you can choose the category at the left and the application at the right (**`Entries`**). Just select the application with a single left click, open the context menu with a right-click and select **`Properties`**. A small window will appear, showing (among other information) the command line.

Those program starter files usually reside in `/usr/share/applications`, so another approach would be to check the `*.desktop` files in that directory. If you're not sure about the name of the `*.desktop` to look for, do a grep from inside the `/usr/share/applications` directory:

```
grep gThumb * | grep 'Name='
```

will give you something like

```
gthumb.desktop:Name=gThumb
gthumb.desktop:X-GNOME-FullName=gThumb Image Viewer
gthumb-import.desktop:Name=Import with gThumb
gthumb-import.desktop:X-GNOME-FullName=gThumb Photo Import Tool
```

Now, you can just use `less gthumb.desktop` to inspect the details of that program starter.

Another way would be to use the **`apropos`** command to search a certain keyword in the man pages.

Answer (score 1):

`for bin in $(for path in $(tr ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH"); do echo $path; done); do ls $bin; done |grep 'disk'`

The above loop enumerates every file in each directory of your `$PATH` and shows any file matching the regex ('disk' in this case) passed to grep at the end of the pipeline.

If you have non-executable files in your `$PATH` this will also show those.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want to hear, but zsh (zshell) does a great job in command completion. It is (backward) compatible to bash so you don't have to learn something completely new.
With [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) there is a good starting point of settings, that can easily be tweaked to your liking.

If I type 'disk' in my terminal it automagically suggests the following list, which can be traversed with .
cfdisk             fdisk              lvmdiskscan        mkdiskimage        sgdisk             udisks             udisks-tcp-bridge  umount.udisks2
cgdisk             gdisk              memdiskfind        sfdisk             testdisk           udisksctl          umount.udisks

As you might have noticed I don't run gnome, so therefore no gnome-disks, but it would have definitely also found that one if it was present.